# Does ARIMA(0,1,11)4 exist?

Tags: arima, notation

I have, without luck, searched to find what an ARIMA model that is differenced once, and has two moving average terms (one at lag 1 and one at lag 4) is called.

The equation for what I am asking for is the following: $(1-B)Y_t= (1-0.5B-0.2B^4)a_t$.

What I have come up with of possibilities are:
ARIMA(0,1,2)4
ARIMA(0,1,1,1)4
ARIMA(0,1,1 1)4

Answer (score 0):

This a ARIMA(0,1,4) model with zero restriction on some of the parameters. Usually nobody fits such types of restricted models, since it is hard to justify the restrictions.

If you really want to give this model a name, you need to invent a new notation. This means stating unambiguously the model and corresponding notation. For example ARIMA(p,d,q) means that the model is written like this

$$(1-\phi_1B-...-\phi_pB^p)(1-B)^dY_t = (1+ \theta_1B+...+\theta_qB^q)Z_t$$

where $Z_t$ is the white noise, and lag polynomials do not have common roots. So you need to write down something similar. Then you need to make this notation known, since the point of the notation is that people understand it in unambiguous way.

Answer (score -1):

No. The reason is because the pdq notation is too simple to define that model. More general solutions like SAS and AUTOBOX , SPSS  and others allow these kinds of models to be formed and estimated. It may be time to put away simple approaches and start to do more comprehensive/correct modelling.

Comment: Thank you for the answer IrishStat. I have identified that model as the most fitting model with SAS PROC ARIMA in SAS BASE 9.4. But i will just write the equation instead, then. 
Thank once again!

Comment: The SAS Proc does not test for the existence of Pulses, Level Shifts , Seasonal Pulses or Local Time Trends AND the constancy of both parameters and error variance over time . These considerations and more warrant you downloading a 30 day free trial of AUTOBOX (which I have helped develop) .

Comment: What i have done is the following:
PROC ARIMA DATA=SASUSER.sales;
*where intervention=0;
IDENTIFY VAR=sales(1) crosscorr=(intervention(1)) nlag=10;
estimate noint q=(1,4) input=(intervention) method=ml;
forecast out=results lead=0;
RUN;

This is, from what i understand a BoxTiao intervention analysis where the test is that the intervention is abrupt and permanent (w).  E.g. Woodfield does the same : http://www.sascommunity.org/sugi/SUGI87/Sugi-12-57%20Woodfield.pdf .
Am i way off?

Comment: I am sorry for the ugly formatting, i am not quite sure how to change that.

Comment: You are doing Intervention Modelling which requires that you pre-specify  the nature of the intervention  and the form of the response.In your case you are specifying a permanent and instantaneous response. Intervention Detection actually Identifies the kind of intervention and the nature of the response.

Comment: Arh, okay. Yes i have tried specifying the intervention in other ways as well, in order to ensure that this is actually the correct pattern. I take it that what i have done is in fact doable and that it is possible from that SAS-statement to conclude that if the intervention variable is significant then a step function is an acceptable way to model the intervention, and its' estimate can be interpreted as the effect of the intervention.
That would also make sense, since what i am modelling is the effect of increasing opening hours in a store. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Often one needs to identify the ARIMA structure after the Intervention has been accounted for rather than before as you probably have done.

Comment: Do you have any references for that, because i would really like to include that in my thesis since the theory that i know of says that the process is: apply ARIMA to the longest timespan (pre/post intervention) and then afterwards apply whole data set to see the effect?

Comment: http://www.autobox.com/cms/index.php/blog/entry/build-or-make-your-own-arima-forecasting-model is an updated flowchart on TF modelling. You are  1) assuming the nature of the intervention  2) assuming that the post intervention ARIMA model is the same as the pre-intervention ARIMA model 3) that the model's errors have constant variance and that there are no other necessary Intervention such as Pulses, seasonal pulses , local time trends. I would nearly guarantee that the residuals are full of structure violating the test that you are reporting.Post your data and I will confirm this.

Comment: What you are saying is worth a lot since i have no other sounding board for this! thank you! 1) The assumption of the nature of the intervention is definitely something that puts the results at risk. 2) modelling the postintervention is unfortunately not possible with only 11 observations (yes, this makes the conclusion even less valid) 3) I have tested the model for ARCH-effects in the residuals hoping this is enough to state variance homogeneity. And lastly i have to assume my way out of other interfering interventions. Unfortunately data is confidential, so it cannot be reposted.

Comment: code your data thus you are not violating any confidentiality agreement.

Comment: ARIMA(p,d,q) is a mathematical definition of a stochastic process. It does not matter which software package implements it (or its variation for that matter). So the comment about the "Hard Time Series" and toys is out of place here.

Comment: The pdq notation is not general enough which is why simple expressions are often ( nearly always !) insufficient.... For example if the model is y(t)=.5*y(t-1)+.5*y(t-3) this is neither a (3,0,0) or a (2,0,0) and certainly there is no room in the pdq notation to deal with empirically identified deterministic series , parameter changes and the error variance deterministic changes.

Comment: "Usually nobody fits such types of restricted models, since it is hard to justify the restrictions."  It is not hard at all when the estimated coefficient for one of the lags is 0.0 or thereabout . The restriiction could be theory based but it could be and perhaps should be based upon empirical findings but that is a lot of effort when you don't have the required functionality to parsimoniously apply the tools of analysis.

Comment: "Then you need to make this notation known, since the point of the notation is that people understand it in unambiguous way." Simply specifiy the number of polynomials and their class(ar or ma) AND the number of coefficients(lags) in each polynomial AND their specific integer lags. This is not too difficult for some but apparently too difficult for others wishing simplicity at the price of efficiency/correctness. Programmers shouldn't rule because of complexity/generality of expression.

Comment: Note that I said that it is hard to justify the restriction, not that it is hard to estimate such type of model. My point concerning the notation was precisely that: state the definition so that others understand it. Modifying the existing notation without specifying what it means is not fruitful.